# Understanding Ionic

Tags: database, cordova, ionic-framework

I am very new to ionic and still trying to learn. Few things I can't get a direct answers on this, hope for some help me. I went through few tutorials are articles, have an basic idea of ionic.

I am trying to develop a "group app". the group has 50 members.
I wish to publish event listings in the group app. Updating will be done
every week. So i can't exactly recompile this into apk whenever I do updating.

Also, I noticed ionic has a template that has login page. Where exactly does the username database stored?

If i need an admin section within ionic app, will it be possible? Whats the recommended method to do this?

If possible, I want this to do without any cost at all. I have a normal wordpress website that uses mysql database.

please help. thank you.

Comment: I just want to give you a hint. First learn Angular and then Ionic. It will help you so much!

Answer (score 10):

> I am very new to ionic and still trying to learn. Few things I can't get a direct answers on this, hope for some help me. I went through few tutorials are articles, have an basic idea of ionic.

it is apparent from your questions, you've been reading recipe and not tutorials. They may have been labeled tutorials, but they were not. You are asking way too many questions, and the topics are too broad (wide).

#### To answer your question, in order

> I am trying to develop a "group app". the group has 50 members. I wish to publish event listings in the group app. Updating will be done every week. So i can't exactly recompile this into apk whenever I do updating.

Your conclusion is based on faulty logic, and not understanding how Cordova works.

> Also, I noticed ionic has a template that has login page. Where exactly does the username database stored?

Username and password storage is your issue, not Cordova's.

> If i need an admin section within ionic app, will it be possible?

Yes.

> Whats the recommended method to do this?

That's up to you. But understand you will be building it your self, likely from scratch.

> If possible, I want this to do without any cost at all. I have a normal wordpress website that uses mysql database.

It is possible, but you will likely want to use a REST API to talk to the mobile App.

As you can see, my response appear to be vague, but that is because your questions are too broad.

I recommend reading this FAQ

[Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)

If you have any further questions, I recommend following up on [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/phonegap) Best of Luck.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to develop a "group app". the group has 50 members. I wish
>   to publish event listings in the group app. Updating will be done
>   every week. So i can't exactly recompile this into apk whenever I do
>   updating.

you can do this using ajax requests to server to get new events
and this is pretty easy by ionic using angular JS but it just need some time to try and read on how to make a restful ionic application
this will help you get the events from the database when the application opened

> Also, I noticed ionic has a template that has login page. Where
>   exactly does the username database stored?

online database, just ready my answer to your first question

> If i need an admin section within ionic app, will it be possible?
>   Whats the recommended method to do this?

yes it is possible but it is not recommended to do it in your public app
better to make web app for that

> If possible, I want this to do without any cost at all. I have a
>   normal wordpress website that uses mysql database.

it will cost you nothing and you can use the MySQL database of your website

Good luck, you can make it, it just need some time and some searches